# Setting default attribute to form select

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I tried  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011586/how-to-set-the-selected-option-in-symfony-forms-select-box/7498180) this solution, but it seams not to work in Symfony 1.4.
Has something changed? How do I add selected attribute to the form select?

Here is my form class:

```
// /lib/form/doctrine/CurrencyListForm.class.php

class CurrencyListForm extends BaseCurrencyForm
{
  public function configure()
  {

    $choices = '';

    $choice = Doctrine::getTable('currency')
        ->createQuery('a')
        ->execute();

    foreach($choice as $v) 
        $choices[$v->getCurrencyCode()] = $v->getCurrencyCode(); 

    $this->setWidgets(array( 
        'currency_code' => new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $choices)), 
    ));

  }

}
```

And this is how I instantiate it:

```
$this->form = new CurrencyListForm();
```

Comment: where do you set the default?

Comment: all my attempts failed. I don't know where.

Comment: It works! How have you come up to it? Dug it deeply?

Comment: I had a sort of similar problem once, and then dug into how the doctrine forms work. and from there on I found out how defaults were set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of form are you rendering? If it's an object form (like `sfFormDoctrine`), the binding 'reverts' the defaults. (It sets the defaults of the model).

What I found was the simplest way to bind it, is creating a dummy object and set the property on that object. Then pass this object to the constructor of the form.

Something like this:

```
$defaultCurrency = new Currency();
$defaultCurrency->currency_code = 'EUR';
$this->form = new CurrencyListForm($defaultCurrency);
```

Comment: // /lib/form/doctrine/CurrencyListForm.class.php

    class CurrencyListForm extends BaseCurrencyForm
 {
   public function configure()
   {
    
    $choices = '';
 
    $choice = Doctrine::getTable('currency')
     ->createQuery('a')
   ->execute();
      
    foreach($choice as $v) 
   $choices[$v->getCurrencyCode()] = $v->getCurrencyCode(); 
      
  $this->setWidgets(array( 
      'currency_code' => new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $choices)), 
  ));
    
   }
   
 }

Comment: you can edit your question and post it there. and please, also add the code where you instantiate your form.

Comment: And if the form is added in configure like $this->widgetSchema['foo'] and there's no explicit object initialization for it, how do I pass checked/selected items?

Comment: $this->widgetSchema['foo']->setDefault(array('value1', 'value2')); does nothing

Comment: It should be passed via render(). Where is it called?